SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 in React and Vite app
I'm developing a web application using React, TypeScript, and Vite. I'm encountering a SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data error in my application. The error occurs in two files: mutation.js and Register.tsx.
// api-client.ts
import { RegisterFormData } from "./pages/Register";
const API_BASE_URL = import.meta.env.VITE_API_BASE_URL;

export const register = async (formData: RegisterFormData) => {
    const response = await fetch(`${API_BASE_URL}/api/users/register`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(formData)
    });

    const responseBody = await response.json();
    if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(responseBody.message);
    }
}

// Register.tsx
const Register = () => {
    const { register, watch, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm<RegisterFormData>();

    const mutation = useMutation(apiCliente.register, {
        onSuccess: () => {
            console.log("Registration Succesful!");
        },
        onError: (error: Error) => {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    });

    const onSubmit = handleSubmit((data) => {
        mutation.mutate(data);
    })
}

It is successfully creating and updating the user to the mongoDB that I am using, yet the onSuccess message is never displayed... Rather an error: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data even though the code is working 'correctly' I wish to understand why is this message showing and how can I fix it so the correct message can be shown.

You'll have to check the Network tab in your browser tools and see what is actually being returned from your server.
